# Postgresql restore with compressed dump file

Tags: pg-dump, pg-restore, postgresql-14

I took a postgresql DB Bacup with the below command

`pg_dump -Z6 -h localhost test_db -f test_db.tar -p port`

Now If I try to restore it with psql facinf the below error:

```
psql:test_db.sql:117359: error: invalid command \gg<CB>t<E4>Iƣ<AC>=<AF>*ESC^TDuV^P^Ov<B6><B0>
psql:test_db.sql:117362: error: invalid command \a>@
psql:test_db.sql:117363: error: invalid command \"<99>k<86>
psql:test_db.sql:117372: error: invalid command \<9B>遥<FD><FE><BA>j
psql:test_db.sql:117406: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8a
```

With pg_restore:

> pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

I thought i was using `-Fc` with pg_dump, but somehow I missed it. Now Can you help me to restore this Backup to postgresql.

I'm Using PostgreSQL 14.5

I've tried below commands

1. `cat test_db.tar | psql test_db -U postgres -h localhost -p port`
2. `\i testdb.tar`
3. even Tried to rename the dump file from test_db.tar to test_db.dump and tried restoring it. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `-Z6` generates a gzipped file.

You can convert that into a plain text SQL script that psql can read using. To unzip it using gzip you will need to rename it, e.g. to `test_db.sql.gz`

Then you can use:

```
gzip -k -d test_db.sql.gz
```

`-k`  will keep the original file

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't mention the format of the dump with -F, by default it created a plain dump file with -Z6 compression and with the extension of .tar

The mistake on my end was that I forgot to mention the dump file format.

After trying the below command, it worked

```
zcat test_db.tar | psql -d test_db -U postgres -h localhost -p port
```